# Is my use of XMLin killing my remote Asterisk AGI script?

Tags: xml, perl, asterisk, telephony, agi

I'm facing a strange problem while using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) module of Perl.

I am writing an Asterisk AGI script in Perl where I am calling a function `someSub()` which uses curl to fetch XML from a CGI page into a variable `$xmlstream`.

I then use `XMLin` on `$xmlstream`. The code is something as shown below:

```
$xmlstream = someSub() ; #uses curl to fetch xml from a cgi page

$xmldata = XMLin($xmlstream, forcearray => 1, suppressempty => '');
```

This works. But, later on in my program when I use the above two lines to fetch new data, the AGI script suddently terminates while executing the second line.

What could be the cause of this bug? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: No error messages? Nothing in log files?

Comment: What happened when you made the smallest possible program to illustrate the problem? Also, why are you using curl instead of LWP::Simple?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please 'use diagnostics' in your Perl program.
Reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html